# Sequelize querying 2 functions connected by $and

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to concatenate two conditions but so far I couldn't figure out the syntaxis:

```
models.trees.findOne({
        where: {
          state: {
            [sequelize.Op.eq]: "Publish",
          },
          $and: 
            [sequelize.where(sequelize.fn("MONTH", sequelize.fn("CURRENT_DATE")), sequelize.fn("MONTH", sequelize.col("createdAt"))),
            sequelize.where(sequelize.fn("YEAR", sequelize.fn("CURRENT_DATE")), sequelize.fn("YEAR", sequelize.col("createdAt")))],
          userId: {
            [sequelize.Op.eq]: id
          },
        },
        attributes: [
          [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("userId")), "count_trees"] 
        ]
    });
```

The issue is with the two conditions in the $and, only the latter is applied, I tried to enclose the different conditions with {} but it throws a syntaxis error.
Any idea of how to apply two functions to the filter where?

Thanks

Comment: you can try to combine them using `sequelize.and`

Comment: Could you give me an example because I tried before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sequelize.and` to combine several `sequelize.where` with functions like this:

```
where: sequelize.and(
  sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('date_part', 'year', sequelize.col('start_date)), '<=',   year),
  sequelize.or(
   sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('date_part', 'year', sequelize.col('end_date')), '>=', year),
   sequelize.where(sequelize.col('end_date'), 'is', null)
  )
)
```